# chessboard: how to draw a non-transparent white piece on an arbitrary position?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chessboard

I have a very simple chessboard question. How can I draw a non-transparent white piece (e.g. pawn) on an arbitrary position on a board, for example, between fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[LSBC1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}
\chessboard[
pgfstyle={[base,at={\pgfpoint{0.5em}{0em}}]text},
text=\setboardfontencoding{LSBC1}\WhitePawnOnWhite,
markfield=d3,
]


\end{document}
```

By default text is centered in the field, with `base` the reference point is at the baseline of the text but still in the middle. 1em is the width of a square.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for a nice code for drawing on an arbitrary position! But I need a non-transparent pawn. Is it possible to add a white non-transparent mask over it?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the "non-transparent" part. You can change the encoding to one with a mask (this won't work with all chessfonts).

Comment: Brilliant! IMHO, you could add this useful example to the documentation. I'd say that it's difficult for a non-expert to figure out from the encoding tables from chessboard.pdf how to achieve this.